# Permissions issues with SQL 2008, Report Builder 2.0

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, report, builder

So here's a bit of context for the horror story:

- Win 2003 SP2 64bit running on a VM exposed to outside world for web access.
- SQL Server 2008 Std SP2 64bit with Reporting Services (RS) installed for native mode (i.e. not sharepoint mode).
- IIS 6 .NET 3.5 web site app written to use the web services from RS. The site has been set to use Windows Authentication and nothing else.
- To save writting custom authentication since I don't need it for this demo I have set-up a local account in Win 2003, i.e. servername\myDemoUser, effectively allow fake Windows Authentication.
- Default.aspx lists folders on RS and the reports from each folder. It also has a link to the Report Builder 2 on the server.
- The rsreportserver.config has been changed so that the only <AuthenticationType> is <RSWindowsNTLM> since <RSWindowsNegoiate> can't work since it's across the internet and users will not be on the same network (hence the local account myDemoUser).
- The web site app has url of the form: http://mysite.mydomain.co.uk/ and the link on it to the Report Builder is of the form: http://mysite.mydomain.co.uk/services/reportbuilder/reportbuilder_2_0_0_0.application, in this case RS has been configured so the Web services virtual directory is "services".
- The web.config for the website app has been set to <identity impersonate="true /> for <locations> for the ASPX pages that access the RS webservice. I even added a <location path="services/reportbuilder"> with the same thing and also to allow anonymous users.

So after all the above I go to the site from a machine that isn't on the network, I get prompted by IE8 for username/password and I enter servername\myDemoUser and the correct password. The homepage is displayed and correctly shows the list of folders and reports from RS. **HOWEVER** if I click the RS report builder link I get the pop window saying it's doing it's clickonce verfication stuff but after a couple of seconds it shows simple message box saying there was an authentication error. The details button then shows a text file with a bunch of stacktrace stuff in which eventually says that the server returned 401 while accessing the .application file mentioned above.

I turned on failure auditing for logins on the Win 2003 VM and I can see that when the clickonce fails it is trying to use the local machine account I logged into on the external (to my network) machine instead of the credentials I entered into the browser on that machine when testing it.

Much Googling and granting of permissions to Network service, everyone etc... on various folders involved later nothing the Report Builder bit just won't install via clickonce due to permissions or the incorrect use there of.

I'm looking into maybe changing something in the RS to try and grant permissions to the report builder to anonymous but at this point I'm pretty pessimistic that I'll actually find anything. The annoying thing about this is that this a test that doesn't represent the final thing (we'll be using custom authentication in RS) but unfortunately I have to do it, 8(.

Any ideas would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when using fake Windows authentication in this way when the machine you are accessing the site from a machine where you have not logged into the domain then clickOnce won't work because it won't pass the details you enter into the browser as found.

So the solution is to:
1) Log into a (any) domain on the machine that is going to access the clickonce link on your site.

2) In Control Panel go to User Accounts (XP)/Store Users and Passwords (Win 2003), and manage the network passwords for a user (XP) and add in the URL, username and password.
Whenever clickonce fires up for this URL it will pass the username/password specified as opposed to the local machine account.

Either of the above will solve this problem.